# Automatically focusing on Field in HTML

Tags: javascript, focus, field

I have a start page with 4 search engines that can be selected. How can I make each field be selected when the search engine is chosen?

Here is one of the engines:

```
<div id="searchrotate" class="body">
    <div class="tab_container">
    <div id="Bing" class="tab_content"><!-- Bing -->
        <div class="searchform">
        <form method="get" action="http://www.bing.com/search" name="bing-search">
            <div class="favicon"><img src="images/favicon-bing.jpg"></div>
            <input type="text" name="q" class="searchfield" value="">
            <input type="image" src="images/search-btn.jpg" class="searchbtn" alt="Submit">
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

...and the css for the "rotation" between the 4 options:

```
#searchhold { width:360px; height:62px; }
#searchselect { width:360px; height:26px; }
#searchselect ul { margin:0; padding:0; float: left; list-style:none; }
#searchselect ul li { float:left; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
#searchselect ul li.current { color:#000; font-weight:bold; background:#ccc; background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #CFCFCF 100%); /* firefox */ background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FFFFFF), color-stop(100%,#CFCFCF)); /* webkit */ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#CFCFCF',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */ }
#searchselect ul li.current a { color:#000; }
#searchselect ul li a { display:block; width:68px; height:14px; padding:6px; text-align:center; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; }
#searchrotate { width:360px; height:36px; background: #cfcfcf; background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #E4E4E4 50%, #CFCFCF 51%, #D9D9D9 100%); /* firefox */ background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FFFFFF), color-stop(50%,#E4E4E4), color-stop(51%,#CFCFCF), color-stop(100%,#D9D9D9)); /* webkit */ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#D9D9D9',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */ }
#searchrotate div.searchform { width:350px; height:26px; padding:5px; }
#searchrotate div.searchform div.favicon { float:left; display:block; width:27px; height:27px; }
#searchrotate input.searchfield { float:left; display:block; width:266px; height:15px; padding:5px; border:1px solid #b0b0b0; background:#535353; color:#fff; font-size:11px; }
#searchrotate input.searchbtn { float:right; display:block; width:44px; height:27px; border:none; background:#a8a8a8; }
```

Comment: `field.focus()` in JavaScript?

Comment: Noob question, but where would I add this?

Comment: on StackOverflow :) Given he also answered your question (below) I think @JCOC611 wasn't trying to suggest the question is too noob, but was checking he hadn't underestimated it. If his is the answer you need, don't forget to accept it!

Comment: Pleasure to help Teknophilia! If you find it useful you may upvote it too.

Comment: I just realized that I misread "Noob question, but where would I add this" as "where would I *ask* this". I think I'll have a coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<div id="clickme" onclick="document.getElementById('bing').focus()">This can be any element</div>
<input type="text" id="bing"/>
```

If you click "clickme" div, the bing input field will be selected. You can do this with almost any type of element (input, div, span, etc) and they can be in any place of the document.

Comment: yea why don't you use jquery or prototype's dollar sign for document.getElementById() instead?

Comment: Because I don't like it, and I want the OP to be able to use plain JavaScript. I like my own framework.

Comment: And I like not using `onclick`. `<script>var elm = document.getElementById("clickme"); if (elm.addEventListener) { elm.addEventListener("click", document.getElementById('bing').focus, false); } else if (elm.attachEvent) { elm.attachEvent("click", document.getElementById('bing').focus); } else { /* does not support DOM? */ }</script>`

Comment: I was trying to point out the simplest answer. Respectable tho.

Comment: @Hello71 - Post that as an answer; since it keeps the HTML cleaner, I for one will vote it up.

Comment: I tried doing the following, but no dice: <div id="Bing" class="tab_content" onclick="document.getElementById('qbing').focus()"><!-- Bing -->
        <div class="searchform">
  <form method="get" action="http://www.bing.com/search" name="bing-search">
   <div class="favicon"><img src="images/favicon-bing.jpg"></div>
   <input type="text" id='qbing' name="q" class="searchfield" value="">
   <input type="image" src="images/search-btn.jpg" class="searchbtn" alt="Submit">
  </form>
  </div>
 </div>